# Homebrew php issues

Tags: php, macos, terminal, homebrew, zsh

So I recently installed php 7.4 with homebrew and I added php to my path, However homebrew mentioned,

```
  For compilers to find php@7.4 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/php@7.4/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/php@7.4/include"
```

So far, it seems like php is working as intended so im not sure if I should run these or not. Could somebody clarify what these commands even do, and should I run them? Thank you.

Also, If I don't need to run them, would it do harm if I were to run them? Im just confused on what they do to begin with.

Comment: Can you use the PHP 7.4 installed by Homebrew? If not, you have to add these into your `.zshrc`, and re-launch the Terminal OR execute `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: @Raptor Yea I can use it but only after I added it to my PATH on my .zprofile file. So can I just ignore those?

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: @Raptor Can you tell me what they do just so I know for the future? Thank you.

Comment: Every library / software has different requirements. Just follow their instructions and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

These are for compilers to find php libraries and header files. `LDFLAGS` is the constant for library path and `CPPFLAGS`is for headers.

Setting these constants might be required for compiling certain PHP extensions.
So, you don't need to run these unless you are doing so. Running them does no harm as these are just exporting the constants.